# How to build maven parent and select number of modules?

Tags: maven-2

I have a multi-module maven project.

To build the parent alone, I run `mvn package -N` (where `-N` is "non-recursive").

To build a few modules, I run `mvn package -pl api,servie` (where `-pl` is "projects").

How do I combine these two in order to build the api, service *and the parent*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
mvn package -pl api,service --also-make
```

(where `--also-make` makes the dependencies as well)

Comment: `--also-make` can be replaced by  `-am`

Answer (score 5):

How about `mvn package -pl api,service,.` ('.' indicating the project in the current directory) or `mvn package -pl api,service,:parent` (where "parent" is the artifactId of the parent module).

Arguments to `-pl` can either be the relative path to a directory containing a maven module or a coordinate in the form `[groupId]:artifactId` of a module in the current project. If no groupId is supplied, the groupId of the pom being built is used.